# SqlClient SqlDbType.Structured barfing at my IEnumerable<int>: "Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1"

Tags: c#, ado.net, ienumerable, sqlclient

I am trying to send an `IEnumerable<int>` to a stored proc on the server, one of whose parameters is a user-defined table type, and I keep getting an error that the value I'm supplying to the parameter cannot be converted to an `IEnumerable<int>`.

{"Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1."}

My user-defined table type on the server is dead simple:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntegerList] AS TABLE(
    [i] [int] NULL
)
```

and the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) say an `IEnumerable<T>` can be used with these table-types via System.Data.SqlClient, which is the library I'm using, not Microsoft.Data.SqlClient:

> System.Data.SqlClient supports populating table-valued parameters from
> DataTable, DbDataReader or IEnumerable T \ SqlDataRecord objects.

So, how to convert a `List<int>` to an `IEnumerable<int>` in a manner that System.Data.SqlClient finds acceptable?  There are many questions about this conversion, but nothing seems to work for me.

I have tried casting **myList** to `IEnumerable<int>` but that doesn't satisfy SqlClient, as the same error occurs when I assign the parameter value with variable `enumerable`:

```
  IEnumerable<int> enumerable = (IEnumerable<int>)myList;

  param2.SqlDBType = SqlDbType.Structured;
  param2.TypeName = "MYDB.dbo.IntegerList"; // user-defined table-type
  param2.Value = enumerable;
```

Comment: I would at least try creating C# type `class IntegerListRow { public int i {get;set;}}` and mapping `List<int>` to `List<IntegerListRow>`. Though I don't have an appropriate setup right now to test.

Comment: @Guru Stron:  Yes, I'm trying alternatives.  DataTable worked, though not at first. You have to be careful not to fully qualify the TypeName when defining the Command parameter. ADO.NET wants `param.TypeName= "dbo.MyType"` not "MYDB.dbo.MyType".

Comment: _"ADO.NET wants `param.TypeName= "dbo.MyType"` not `"MYDB.dbo.MyType"`. "_ - this kind of makes sense since you are already have connected to the database.

Comment: @Guru Stron: I can't get the `List<IntegerListRow>` to work.  Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it's just not supported. ADO.NET throws an error when it is sent a `List<IntegerListRow>`.

Comment: Then use your approach with Datatable

Comment: Now I know why you're called "Guru" Stron, oh wise one.

Comment: Hahahhaha, nice one!)))

Comment: BTW fell free to post and accept your answer, since it seems you have solved the issue)

Comment: I made this for something different but maybe can help you with some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69574353/888472 and instead of a datatable you can reach a List<T> or IEnumerable<T>